# model->save() always uses 'insert' even though id is given

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm using CakePHP v2.3.5. When I update the table

```
`users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(320) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'SG',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

using `$this->User->save($this->request->data)`, it always fires an insert command and throws

```
"Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '10' for key 'PRIMARY'"
```

The `request->data` object is:

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'id' => '10',
        'firstname' => 'Someone',
        'lastname' => 'Surname',
    )
)
```

The complete action I'm using now is:

```
public function addInfo() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->User->create();
        $this->User->id=(int)$this->request->data['User']['id'];
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {

        }

    }
}
```

And the beforeSave function in Model is:

> public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
>
> ```
>    if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])) {
>        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
>    }
>    return true;
> ```
>
> }

In User Object, this id=>false looked fishy to me

> object(User) {
>     displayField => 'firstname'
>     primaryKey => 'id'
>     useDbConfig => 'default'
>     useTable => 'users'
>     id => false
>     data => array(
>         [maximum depth reached]
>     )
>   }

Comment: Try with `'id'=>10` (10 as integer) in the `request->data` array

Comment: Thanks for editing the post. Casting id as integer, 'User' => array('id' => (int) 10,'firstname' => 'Someone','lastname' => 'Surname') but problem persist.

Comment: Please show your entire controller action code. Just quoting the save method you are using isn't going to help us help you.

Comment: what happens if you hardcode `$this->User->id = 10;` right before the save action?

Comment: I hardcoded $this->User->id, still the same. Then I try hardcoded the user id followed by unset($this->request->data['User']['id']), it inserted as a new row.

Comment: and what ID did that new row get?

Comment: well if you set the ID to 10 and give only an array with firstname and lastname to the model it is beyond my why it would create a new row

Comment: You need to look at/show the sql log - and particularly the find immediately before the save that is finding 0 rows.

Comment: Am I misreading this or are you trying to update a user that already exists? If so, the create() call is unnecessary.

Comment: The create() call was added following suggestion of Nunser. $this->element('sql_dump'); not working when there is 'Database Error' of integrity constrain, how do I check the query before the error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. I happened to have a function in Model called `getId` and CakePHP was also using `getId` to check the existence of the row, hence,  it always got negative result when checking by id so it fired an insert call instead of update call. Thanks everyone for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Do a create before the save

```
$this->User->create();
$this->User->save($this->request->data); //with the id cast as integer
```

[create](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-create-array-data-array) is for reseting the model, so even if it is an update, you should call that function as a precaution.

Comment: It still firing 'insert' query with "Integrity constraint violation" error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a value, rather than create a new one, make sure your are passing the primary key field into the data array:

```
$data = array('id' => 10, 'firstname' => 'Someone', 'lastname'=> 'Surname');
// This will update User with id 10

$this->User->save($data);
```

Comment: No, I wanted to update the row, so I didn't 'create' the record. If I not wrong 'create' is meant for 'insert' action.

Comment: It still fired the 'insert' sql query.

Comment: Then I am guessing you are doing something else in your controller or model (beforeSave), could you show the complete action of your controller in your initial post and if present the beforeSave in the Model

Comment: Edited my initial post with complete action, beforeSave in Model and part of my User object.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ID before saving:

```
$this->User->id = useridhere
$this->Users->save($this->request->data);
```

Comment: Tried adding $this->User->id=(int)$this->request->data['User']['id']; before save. And tested $this->User->exists($this->request->data['User']['id']) return 1. But still got 'insert' sql instead of 'update'

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem here. I've tried different configuration (with save(), saveAll(), saveMany(), saveAssociated(), with *deep* option), later I found out that my table has different primary key (the primary field name wasn't "id"). Adding primary field name to my model solves the problem.

```
class SomeModel extends AppModel {

    public $primaryKey = "different_primary_field_name_for_id";

}
```